# Filter <SELECT> options based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

I have 2 input selects

Country and Cars

This is the structure: [https://jsfiddle.net/CornerStone20/r1eanhwv/6/][1]

**JSFIDDLE:** [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/CornerStone20/r1eanhwv/6/

When I select Country, How do I only show the selected country's cars?

I have tried:

```
$(function() {
    $('#Country_Select').on('change', function() {
        var val = this.value;
        $('#Cars_Select option').hide().filter(function() {
            return this.value.indexOf( val + '_' ) === 0;
        })
        .show();
    })
    .change();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each` loop to iterate through options and check if the value of `car` select- box is same as `country` select-box depending upon this `show()` or `hide()` options .

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#Country_Select').on('change', function() {
    var val = this.value;
    $('#Cars_Select option').each(function() {
      //checking value of opton in cars selct is same
      if ($(this).val() == val) {
        $(this).show(); //show it
      } else {
        $(this).hide(); //hide other
      }
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// Country select
<select id="Country_Select" class="form-control">
  <option selected="true" disabled="false">Choose Country</option>
  <option value="0001">France</option>
  <option value="8ebd9ec1-b121-44e9-a530-42f227359913">Germany</option>
  <option value="4dda2683-83c6-48c8-af9b-0a96991b7c8b">New Zealand</option>
</select>


// Cars

<select id="Cars_Select" class="form-control">
  <option selected="true" disabled="false">Choose Cars</option>
  <option value="0001">Renauld</option>
  <option value="0001">Mini</option>
  <option value="0001">Paris</option>
  <option value="8ebd9ec1-b121-44e9-a530-42f227359913">BMW</option>
  <option value="8ebd9ec1-b121-44e9-a530-42f227359913">Audi</option>
  <option value="8ebd9ec1-b121-44e9-a530-42f227359913">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="8ebd9ec1-b121-44e9-a530-42f227359913">Benz</option>
  <option value="4dda2683-83c6-48c8-af9b-0a96991b7c8b">Kiwi Auto</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though the question has been answered, I am writing a better approach here:

```js
$('#Country_Select').on('change', function(e) {
  let cars = $('#Cars_Select').children();
  cars.hide();
  let country = $(this).val();
  cars.filter('[value=' + country + ']').add(cars.eq(0)).show();
});
```